# Xelatex not rendering selected IPA fonts

Tags: fonts, xetex, tipa

I am trying to render som IPA fonts on a Page.

```
% Headers\RequirePackage{silence} % :-\
    \WarningFilter{scrreprt}{Usage of package `titlesec'}
    %\WarningFilter{scrreprt}{Activating an ugly workaround}
    \WarningFilter{titlesec}{Non standard sectioning command detected}
\documentclass[ twoside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,%1headlines,
                headinclude,footinclude,cleardoublepage=empty,abstract=on,
                BCOR=5mm,paper=a5,fontsize=9pt,svgnames
                ]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.5cm}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\newfontfamily\hindifont{Noto Sans Devanagari}[Script=Devanagari] % Use any Devanagari font on your system

% --- Sample Script

Consonants
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{ccccccccccc}
{[}p{]} & pig  & {[}pig{]}  &  & {[}θ{]}  & think    & {[}θiŋk{]}   &  & {[}h{]} & hand  & {[}hænd{]} \\
{[}b{]} & box  & {[}bɑks{]} &  & {[}ð{]}  & this     & {[}ðis{]}    &  & {[}m{]} & man   & {[}mæn{]}  \\
{[}t{]} & time & {[}taim{]} &  & {[}s{]}  & sun      & {[}sʌn{]}    &  & {[}n{]} & nose  & {[}nouz{]} \\
{[}d{]} & dog  & {[}dɔg{]}  &  & {[}z{]}  & zoo      & {[}zu:{]}    &  & {[}ŋ{]} & wing  & {[}wiŋ{]}  \\
{[}k{]} & cat  & {[}kæt{]}  &  & {[}ʃ{]}  & shoe     & {[}ʃuː{]}    &  & {[}r{]} & run   & {[}rʌn{]}  \\
{[}g{]} & go   & {[}gou{]}  &  & {[}Ʒ{]}  & treasure & {[}tréʒǝr{]} &  & {[}l{]} & light & {[}lait{]} \\
{[}f{]} & face & {[}feis{]} &  & {[}tʃ{]} & chair    & {[}tʃεǝr{]}  &  & {[}j{]} & year  & {[}jiǝr{]} \\
{[}v{]} & vase & {[}veis{]} &  & {[}dƷ{]} & juice    & {[}dʒuːs{]}  &  & {[}w{]} & west  & {[}west{]}
\end{tabular}%
}\\
Vowel
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{ccccccccccc}
\multicolumn{7}{c}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Monophthongs \\ (single, pure vowel sound)\end{tabular}} &
   &
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Diphthongs\\ (two vowel sounds \\ joined in one syllable)\end{tabular}} \\
{[}i:{]} & feet  & {[}fi:t{]}   &  & {[}ǝ{]}  & bird & {[}bǝrd{]}  &  & {[}ai{]} & eye   & {[}ai{]}   \\
{[}i{]}  & fish  & {[}fiʃ{]}{]} &  & {[}u:{]} & two  & {[}tu:{]}   &  & {[}au{]} & mouse & {[}maus{]} \\
{[}e{]}  & bed   & {[}bed{]}    &  & {[}u{]}  & book & {[}buk{]}   &  & {[}ɔi{]} & toy   & {[}tɔi{]}  \\
{[}æ{]}  & apple & {[}æpl{]}    &  & {[}ɔ{]}  & ball & {[}bɔl{]}   &  & {[}ju{]} & you   & {[}ju{]}   \\
{[}ʌ{]}  & sun   & {[}sʌn{]}    &  & {[}ɑ{]}  & mama & {[}m'ɑmɑ{]} &  & {[}ei{]} & cake  & {[}keik{]} \\
{[}ǝ{]}  & alive & {[}ǝl'aiv{]} &  &          &      &             &  & {[}ou{]} & go    & {[}gou{]} 
\end{tabular}%
}
```

Now some of the fonts are being rendered but some are not getting rendered, for example notice the `shoe` sign `ʃ`.

[image]

Am I missing any package or is it logical error?

Comment: if you don't show what packages you are using it is hard to say what is wrong. please edit your question so that it has a full test document that produces the output shown, and people can debug.

Comment: unrelated but avoid using `\resizebox` on tables (or any text) it destroys any chance of having consistent fonts in the document.

Comment: I assume from your tagging that you are using xelatex presumably the font you have chosen does not have the full range of characters that you need (check the log for missing character warnings) You can choose another font.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am using the ClassicThesis package by Andre. It has a number of packages in its config. However, I am attaching the basic ones I have used in the main file.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That is a good point you noticed, I am struggling with scaling down oversized tables. I tried `resizebox`, `adjustbox`. But settled with `\resizebox`. What do you refer to use in place of `\resizebox` to shrink down oversized tables. Note that it's all maths so I don't want them breaking the line.

Comment: resizebox scalebox adjustbox doesn't matter the point is that you should not use any scaling. If you can not make the table fit at normalsize choose a smaller named size such as `\small` or `\footnotesize` don't just squish the table by some arbitrary amount to make it fit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simply a matter of choosing a font that has the characters.

If you use xelatex's default computer modern, the log file will show multiple

```
Missing character: There is no ʃ in font [lmroman10-regular]:mapping=tex-text;!
```

If I switch to Arial then there are no such warnings and all the characters appear, many other fonts will be available, but no font covers all of Unicode so you need to pick one that covers the range you need.

I removed the `\resizebox`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\begin{document}

\centering

Consonants

\begin{tabular}{@{}ccccccccccc@{}}
[p] & pig  & [pig]  &  & [θ]  & think    & [θiŋk]   &  & [h] & hand  & [hænd] \\\relax
[b] & box  & [bɑks] &  & [ð]  & this     & [ðis]    &  & [m] & man   & [mæn]  \\\relax
[t] & time & [taim] &  & [s]  & sun      & [sʌn]    &  & [n] & nose  & [nouz] \\\relax
[d] & dog  & [dɔg]  &  & [z]  & zoo      & [zu:]    &  & [ŋ] & wing  & [wiŋ]  \\\relax
[k] & cat  & [kæt]  &  & [ʃ]  & shoe     & [ʃuː]    &  & [r] & run   & [rʌn]  \\\relax
[g] & go   & [gou]  &  & [Ʒ]  & treasure & [tréʒǝr] &  & [l] & light & [lait] \\\relax
[f] & face & [feis] &  & [tʃ] & chair    & [tʃεǝr]  &  & [j] & year  & [jiǝr] \\\relax
[v] & vase & [veis] &  & [dƷ] & juice    & [dʒuːs]  &  & [w] & west  & [west]
\end{tabular}

Vowel

\begin{tabular}{@{}ccccccccccc@{}}
\multicolumn{7}{c}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Monophthongs \\ (single, pure vowel sound)\end{tabular}} &
   &
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Diphthongs\\\relax (two vowel sounds \\\relax joined in one syllable)\end{tabular}} \\\relax
[i:] & feet  & [fi:t]   &  & [ǝ]  & bird & [bǝrd]  &  & [ai] & eye   & [ai]   \\\relax
[i]  & fish  & [fiʃ]] &  & [u:] & two  & [tu:]   &  & [au] & mouse & [maus] \\\relax
[e]  & bed   & [bed]    &  & [u]  & book & [buk]   &  & [ɔi] & toy   & [tɔi]  \\\relax
[æ]  & apple & [æpl]    &  & [ɔ]  & ball & [bɔl]   &  & [ju] & you   & [ju]   \\\relax
[ʌ]  & sun   & [sʌn]    &  & [ɑ]  & mama & [m'ɑmɑ] &  & [ei] & cake  & [keik] \\\relax
[ǝ]  & alive & [ǝl'aiv] &  &          &      &             &  & [ou] & go    & [gou{]} 
\end{tabular}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The issue was with the font, I am now using `\newfontfamily\splfont{EB Garamond}` and `{\splfont ʃ}` to eradicate the issue. Thanks again for your time. And I'll try to redefine the font sizes of oversized tables.